# How to use google sms retriever api with jetpack compose in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect a 4-digit sms code from the service and auto-fill the otp boxes I make. I used google documentation for this, the source I used is:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

I write with jetpack compose, so I am having a little difficulty adapting it. I have more than one screen, but the operation is briefly as follows, it comes to a screen where the user information and phone number are entered, after entering the information, I press the continue button and when I press the button, I send the user's information and phone number to the service, an sms is sent from the service to the user's phone number. Of course, when he presses the continue button, he goes to the other screen. There are 4 boxes on the verification screen, I want these boxes to be filled automatically when the user's phone receives an sms. I followed the path in the google documentation of this, I tried to do the things written on the internet, but I could not find a result because some did not do it with compose and some did not share working code and some are out of date.

I briefly explained what I want to do, it's actually something that happens in most applications, but I don't know because I have never done anything like this before and I don't have much experience, so it would be great if he guides me in detail, at least by supporting it with code.

here are the codes i made

**screen where I want user information, phone number, name, surname, etc.**

```
@Composable
fun UserFormScreenRoute(
   
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    viewModel: UserFormViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()


    UserFormScreen(
        
        sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel,
        state = state,
        postRegister = viewModel::postRegister,
        ...
    )

}


@Composable
fun UserFormScreen(
   
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    state: UserFormScreenState,
    postRegister: (RegisterUiModel) -> Unit,
    ...
) {
    .
    .
    . // other informations and other components etc. it is not very important 

    DYTLoginAndContinueButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.devam),
        navController = null,
        route = null,
        enabled = buttonEnabled(state)
    ) {

        postRegister(
            RegisterUiModel(
                email = "",
                phone = getOnlyPhoneNumber(),
                name = state.name,
                birthdate = state.birthDate,
                gender = state.gender.get(),
                password = state.password,
                eatingHabit = sharedViewModel.registerData?.eatingHabit,
                wellnessGoal = sharedViewModel.registerData?.wellnessGoal,
                token = "xxx",
                dialCode = "90"//state.phoneCode.substring(1) ?: "90"
            )
        )
    }

}
```

DYTLoginAndContinueButton is a button. it navigates verification code screen when user click this button and send user's phone number to the service to send sms code to user

**hear is my code verification screen**

```
@Composable
fun VerificationPhoneCodeRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: VerificationPhoneCodeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {


    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    VerificationPhoneCodeScreen(
        navHostController = navHostController,
        state = state,
        onChangeOtpValue = viewModel::onChangeOtpValue,
        verificationSmsCode = viewModel::verificationSmsCode, 
        setError = viewModel::setError,
    )
}


@Composable
fun VerificationPhoneCodeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state: VerificationPhoneCodeScreenState,
    onChangeOtpValue: (String) -> Unit,
    verificationSmsCode: (String) -> Unit,
    setError: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {


    if (state.error) {
        CustomAlertDialog(
            text = "error!",
            ButtonText = "okey",
            onChangeError = {
                setError(it)
            }
        )
    }



    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            BackPopUp(
                navController = navHostController,
                route = RegisterScreen.SignUpUserFormScreen.route
            )
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {

            Text(
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                text = please enter your sms code below field,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
            )

            OtpTextField(
                otpText = state.otpValue,
                otpVerificationStatus = state.otpVerificationStatus,
                onOtpTextChange = { value, otpInputFilled ->
                    onChangeOtpValue(value)
                    if (otpInputFilled) {
                        verificationSmsCode(value)
                    }
                }
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                text = state.phoneNumber
            )

        }
    }
}
```

**OtpTextField**

```
@Composable
fun OtpTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    otpVerificationStatus: OtpVerificationStatus,
    otpText: String,
    otpCount: Int = 4,
    onOtpTextChange: (String, Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (otpText.length > otpCount) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Otp text value must not have more than otpCount: $otpCount characters")
        }
    }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = TextFieldValue(otpText, selection = TextRange(otpText.length)),
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.text.length <= otpCount) {
                onOtpTextChange.invoke(it.text, it.text.length == otpCount)
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword),
        decorationBox = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(15.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                repeat(otpCount) { index ->
                    CharView(
                        index = index,
                        text = otpText,
                        otpVerificationStatus
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun CharView(
    index: Int,
    text: String,
    otpVerificationStatus: OtpVerificationStatus
) {



    val isFocused = text.length == index
    val char = when {
        index == text.length -> "0"
        index > text.length -> ""
        else -> text[index].toString()
    }


    var focusedColor = MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor
    var nonFocusedColor = MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor

    when(otpVerificationStatus){

        OtpVerificationStatus.DEFAULT -> {
            focusedColor = MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor
            nonFocusedColor = MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor
        }

        OtpVerificationStatus.VERIFICATION_TRUE -> {
            focusedColor = DYTGreenColor
            nonFocusedColor = DYTGreenColor
        }

        OtpVerificationStatus.VERIFICATION_FALSE -> {
            focusedColor = red_color
            nonFocusedColor = red_color
        }
    }


    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp, 60.dp)
            .border(
                2.dp, when {
                    isFocused -> focusedColor
                    else -> nonFocusedColor
                }, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .padding(2.dp)
            .offset(y = 15.dp),
        text = char,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

**MySMSBroadcastReceiver**

```
class MySMSBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
            val extras = intent.extras
            val status = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

            when (status.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                    val message = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE) as String
                    println("SMS CODE MESSAGE -> "+message)
                }
                CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

I added this code into manifest application tag

```
 <receiver android:name=".diyetkolikfeature.ui.register.signup.verificationphonecodescren.components.MySMSBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Build.gradle**

I added these too in my build.gradle dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
```

**MainActivity**

I thought it would be right to add mainactivity because I don't know where to install this part.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)


        val task: Task<Void> = client.startSmsRetriever()


        task.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Void?> {

        })

        task.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {

        })

        setContent {

            DiyetkolikTheme {
                navHostController = rememberNavController()
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    RootNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so `onReceive` is not getting called? And your message contains retriever hash at the end, right? I had same problems because of wrong retriever hash, the easiest way I've found is using [`AppSignatureHelper.java`](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java)

Comment: so I checked . Is it enough to just add AppSignatureHelper.java? because there are other things

Comment: I added AppSignatureHelper class in my project and I gave TIMEOUT code = 15 response from onReceive. Why am i getting this error ?

Comment: you need to create an object and call `getAppSignatures` method - this will give you the retriever hash, a string that should be added on the server side per the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify)